# Is there any plugin or anything to limit specific user access media manager?

Tags: joomla

I need to make an account for people to edit a part of my website, but they just need to update a small part frequently.

However, when they upload an image for the article, they are able to access all of the images in my site.

Is there a way to limit the access of images? Can I preset another image root path which is the sub-path of the original image path for the specific user?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JCE (JoomlaContentEditor), it's the best editor available and allows you to lock down image paths specific to your users. (i.e. JohnDoe is logged in --> in the config you've specified a path for all images --> JohnDoe folder doesn't exist in the image folder --> folder is created and JohnDoe only has access to those files that he places in there).

Great Editor: http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/

Be sure to get the component and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

JCE works great -BUT, if the user uses the images/links tab to insert a intro/full image, JCE profiles will not work.  The images root is the default path for uploading images via the images/links tab.  The user will need to be mindful of what folder they are loading the images to.